# STDEV aggregation as core function

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is there any possibility to call STDEV aggregation function from entity framework core?
I searched source and came to no solution.

Comment: If you mean as a linq to sql function, no i believe, you will have to write it dbside or do it in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is only supported by a workaround. I opened up a [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11850).

The workaround uses the `fromSql()` Methode.

```
class ScalarResult<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Benchmark> Benchmarks { get; set; }
    public DbQuery<ScalarResult<double>> Doubles { get; set; }
}


var db = new MyContext();
var stdev = Enumerable.Single(
    from r in db.Doubles.FromSql("SELECT STDEV(Result) AS Value FROM Benchmarks") select r.Value);
```

This is a solution from Brice Lambson (thanks).